# A* search variance

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for a path searching algorithm that is similar to A* search, but taking into account a integral function over that searched path. In particular, here is the problem:

> For each point P in the search space, there is a function f(P). Along any path AB, you can integrate ![formula](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cint_%7BA%7D%5E%7BB%7D%20f(P)) (an energy spent on the path). Now I need to find an optimal path which we spend the less total energy.

An A* search algorithm would ask for an *admissible* h(n) - a heuristic that estimates the cost of the cheapest path from n to the goal. I, however, couldn't find a good admissible function like that.

Any direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: Any function h(n) that never overestimates the integral would be an admissible heuristic. Without knowing anything about f(P), it's hard to say what function you could use for h() other than the constant zero function.

Comment: This sounds like a calculus of variations problem. Unless your path happens to be composed of a finite set of line segments.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Yes the space in my problem is quantized, so there is only a limited number of nodes.

Comment: @TedHopp Here is the details of my problem: I have a simulated environment, in which an agent need to move an object from A to B. I need to plan the path so that the agent spend the least energy, or most economical. I believe this problem must has been addressed somewhere, but I haven't found its solution so far. Also the agent is basically a human rig with bones and joints from Final IK (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14290)

Comment: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: @JaredGoguen so it is basically just leave h(n) to be 0. Ok not exactly what I'm looking for but it might be the best I could have.